# Remove node and nodejs from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nodejs

I have node and `nodejs` installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I want to remove it and/or reinstall it to have latest `nodejs` version.

- When I run `node -v` it gives me: `v12.18.4`
- When I run `nodejs -v` it gives me: `v8.10.0`

Also

- `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`
- `which nodejs` returns `/usr/bin/nodejs`

I tried to uninstall them with

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
```

but `sudo apt-get --purge remove node` gives me

`E: Unable to locate package node`

and `sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs` returns

```
npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: How you properly uninstall something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. apt-get only knows about deb packages. It's never heard of other methods (like Snaps, AppImages. install scripts, compiled, pip, venv, etc.) and cannot help you with them.

Comment: it should be installed via apt-get

Comment: Software installed using apt-get don't get installed to /usr/local/bin. That version of node was clearly installed some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed them via a tar file or something similar, they might be in $PATH or /usr/share, but this depends on how you installed your package.

If NodeJS was not installed via APT, APT will not find it. I would suggest maybe searching for nodejs and node files with `find / -name "node*"` and removing them manually or if the installer came with an uninstaller, use that instead.

Comment: I used dpkg-query -L nodejs and got /.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/node
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/nodejs
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nodejs
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/AUTHORS.gz
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
/usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz


Should I remove all of those node folders manually?

Comment: If nothing else works, then yes. That is how I removed MySQL when it broke my system. Removed every DPKG package and it no longer breaks my OS.